Proof verification: simpler steps for proving Cauchy's theorem for Abelian groups
Cauchy's theorem for groups states that if prime $p$ divides $|G|$, then there exists $x \in G$ such that $\mathrm{ord}(x) = p$. This proof requires some heavy machinery even for the finite Abelian case or at least induction. I wanted to find a simpler proof using infinite descent.
My proof goes as follows, $(G,+)$ is a finite abelian group:
If $|G| = p$, we are done. If $|G| \neq p$, then it has at least one proper non-trivial subgroup $H$. Because $G$ is abelian, $H$ is normal and therefore the quotient group $N = G \setminus H$ exists. By Lagrange's theorem, $|N||H| = |G|$, but it is important to note that $N$ is not a subgroup of $G$. Notice also that in this step we do not make a mistake by claiming that $H$ is a cyclic subgroup.
Consider now, as a set, the direct product $N \times H$ for which we identify $(n, h)$ as elements. By (elementary) set theory there exists a bijection $f:G\to N \times H$.
We can make $N \times H$ into a group by defining $\circ$, such that $f(n+h) = f(n) \circ f(h)$. From this we also have the (trivial) maps by $f(n) \circ f(0)$ and $f(0) \circ f(h)$. Additionally, $f$ is now a group isomorphism, we can simply "preserve" the structure of $+$. The existence of $\circ$ is guaranteed by Axiom of Choice -- we can simply pick one by one the elements where $f(n) \circ f(h)$ "ought" to go.  This is the "heavy machinery" in this proof, though the sets being finite might be enough to just simply state this as a matter of fact.
Now the order of $(n,0)$ in $N \times H$ is just $|N|$ by definition and order is closed under isomorphism. Therefore there is an element $n \in G$ with $\mathrm{ord}(n) = |N|$. This implies $G$ has a normal subgroup $N'$ with $|N'| = |N|$.
Now finally if $|G| \neq p^k, k\geq 2$, then either $p$ divides $|H|$ or $p$ divides $|N'|$. Both are abelian, so we can infinitely descend until we find some subgroup $|M| = p$. If $|G| = p^k$, we can pick $H$ and infinitely descend. The proof is now complete.
I would like to get some reviews on the proof and identification of any errors whether it is sound or not. Is the usage of Axiom of Choice here correct or how would I better use it here?

Why do you think you are using the AC here? Also, the assumption that every proof of Cauchy's Lemma uses "heavy machinery" is wrong. For general groups, there is a short well-known proof that considers the $C_p$-set ${g \in G^p : g_1 \cdots g_p = 1}$. And for abelian groups there is a well-known proof using quotient groups, which you can see in the forum (they are already linked here on the right, for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893965 any many more). About your proof: it is very odd to define a group just to realize later that it is $\cong G$. Omit the detour.

@MartinBrandenburg would you suggest to reword it in the proof as "by countable choice" instead? I don't think there is anything else we can say about there existing an isomorphism. This of course made me scratch my head and I wanted to avoid using it.

From the description of the solution-verification tag: " "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so."

Choice is not needed to make finitely many choices. If you are trying to do a proof of Cauchy's Theorem, then you are working in a finite set.

There are several issues with your proof - unfortunately I don't think it can be fixed. You might want to consider the following points, try out some examples with small abelian, and see what goes wrong with your attempt. (The discussion about axiom of choice seems less relevant.)

At the end of the proof, you conclude that there exists $n \in G$ with $ord(n) = |N|$. But this is not true! So there is something wrong with your strategy. For example, consider $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (direct product of three cyclic groups of order $2$). Then there is a non-trivial proper subgroup $H \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (one of the factors for example), with quotient $G/H$ of order $4$. There is no element of order $4$ in $G$, every element has order $1$ or $2$.

You have bijection $f: G \rightarrow N \times H$. Then you talk about $f(n+h)$ for $n \in N$ and $h \in H$, which does not make sense when $N$ is the quotient group. The elements of $N = G/H$ are not elements of $G$; they are cosets: $G/N = \{gH : g \in G\}$.

Basically it is unclear how you define $\circ$ on $N \times H$. Then in the end you claim $f$ is an isomorphism $G \rightarrow N \times H$. So as noted in a comment, it is also unclear why this construction is needed.

A minor point is that the quotient is usually denoted by $G/H$. Meanwhile $G \setminus H$ usually denotes the set $\{x \in G : x \not\in H\}$ (complement of $H$ in $G$).


